# How can I prevent exceptions that aren't caused by user code?

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app in the store that seems to be crashing some.  This would normally be easy to fix, but the exceptions seem to be occurring deep in the Windows API.  When I was originally developing my app, I never experienced any of these exceptions.  I've also searched online, but can't seem to find anything about these.
[Here's an Excel Online workbook with stack trace and exception data.](http://1drv.ms/1FETgvO) (OneDrive)
**My question is, how can I solve these exceptions and prevent them in the future?**

Comment: Although your exceptions come from the Windows-API they may be caused by your actual program. Imagine deviding a number by zero. Of course you´d get an exception from windows, but the actual cause was your program, so you´d have to handle those exceptions anyway.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I understand what you're saying, and I've applied that to my app already in situations where there's a reasonable chance for an exception to be thrown.  On the other hand, the stack traces don't contain anything related to my written code (which is where I'm getting confused).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to catch all exceptions on a Windows Phone app, as some of them are caused by instabilities at the OS level. However, you can catch many of them by setting a global exception handler.

First, subscribe to the `UnhandledException` event in the app constructor:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException; 
}
```

In the event handler, set `e.Handled` to `true`:

```
void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I'd also recommend to add a way to log the exceptions and automatically send them to you, as you may be hiding legitimate errors that you could/should fix.